# WSO2 MDM Connection Failer

Tags: wso2

Im trying to setup WSO2MDM on Nexus 07 tablet.

I have configured web based backend and its up and running.
I followed the guide lines in documentation to set up Client mobile app on the tablet. (Already set the configuration according to steps on documentation and compiled it.)

But When I try to register using tablet it gives me an error saying "Authentication failed due to a connection failure do you want to try again?";

Please advise me how to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

What's the authentication parameters you tried? In a fresh pack, you may not have configured tenants. So your basic login parameters can be "admin", "admin" as the user name and password. That's basically the super admin's credentials.

First check whether you can enroll the device to that user. Then try with the new user you have created. Always keep the Domain field empty if you do not have a tenant set up. And if you are trying this setup in your local machine, make sure your device and server are in the same network. Android WIFI tethering may help you in that case.

Use this guide[1] when you are enrolling.

[1] - http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/03/how-wso2-emm-addresses-the-android-challenge/

Thanks

Comment: By the way, if you are using a Windows laptop to test this, please switch off firewalls. Otherwise device will not be able to connect.

Comment: I tried to compile and run the app using eclipse. It gives me this error. I have attached a screenshot with this.

[code]
06-10 15:05:53.447: W/System.err(17459):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-10 15:05:53.447: V/WSO2MDM(17459): Posting '{password=admin, username=admin}' to https://10.1.10.68:9443/emm/api/users/authenticate
06-10 15:05:53.447: V/WSO2MDM(17459): Posting 'password=admin&username=admin' to users/authenticate
06-10 15:05:53.447: E/WSO2MDM(17459): Failed to register on attempt 1

[/code]

Comment: Hi, Since you are using a customized Agent Code. You have a configuration issue on it. FInd CommonUtilities.java file on your Agent source code utils package, keep SERVER_PROTOCOL field to http:// and port to 9763. And try again. If you want to move to HTTPS you need to generate the BKS certificate using the server SSL certificate and put it inside Android Agent's res/raw folder.

Comment: Use this guide [1] as well when you configure. [1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Android+Configurations